# ASP.NET MVC With Kendo UI Grid Cannot Create Update and Destroy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to build ASP.NET App using Kendo UI and I face a problem when I want to Create, Update, and Destroy. There is no Error When I built it. It Display Well and when I try to add something, It goes as it should. It still Display what I just Create. but After I refresh the page that data isn't there.
And Nothing Change on Database, no data added.

Here's my Controller:

```
public ActionResult _Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var u = db.Unit.Select(n => new { n.UnitID,n.KodeUnit, n.NamaUnit, n.JumlahPegawai });
        DataSourceResult result = u.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Unit> unit)
    {
        var results = new List<Unit>();

        if (unit != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var u in unit)
            {
                db.Unit.Add(u);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Unit> unit)
    {
        if (unit != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var u in unit)
            {
                db.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(new[] { unit }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Unit> unit)
    {
        if (unit.Any())
        {
            foreach (var u in unit)
            {
                db.Unit.Remove(u);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(unit.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

And Here's my Model:

```
namespace Aplikasi_PKPT.Models
{

public class Unit
    {
    [Key]
    public int UnitID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Kode Unit")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Kode Unit Tidak Boleh Kosong")]
    public string KodeUnit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nama Unit")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nama Unit Tidak Boleh Kosong")]
    [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Nama Unit Tidak Boleh Melebihi 60 Karakter")]
    public string NamaUnit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Jumlah Pegawai")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Jumlah Pegawai Tidak Boleh Kosong")]
    public int JumlahPegawai { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pkpt> Pkpt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Korkel> Korkel { get; set; }
}
```

}

And Here's my Index View:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Aplikasi_PKPT.Models.Unit>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(id => id.UnitID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("_Index", "Unit"))
        .Create(update => update.Action("_Create","Unit"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("_Update", "Unit"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("_Destroy", "Unit"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(u => u.KodeUnit);
        columns.Bound(u => u.NamaUnit);
        columns.Bound(u => u.JumlahPegawai);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
        }
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
        toolbar.Create();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Events(e => e.Edit("hideIdField"))

)
    <script>
        function hideIdField(e) {
            $("#UnitID").hide();
            $("label[for='UnitID']").hide();
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Any Help Would be apreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you binding IEnumerable?

Please try this code for create action.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult _Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Unit unit)
{
    if (unit != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Unit.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

If this works, then change update and delete action in similar way like create action.

Comment: Hi Edin, Thank You very much. I only followed in the documentation example on Kendo UI website. but I don't know whether it's because I am using MVC 5 or something..